Error while getting a @RequestParam or @RequestBody from HTML Form
I have a simple HTML form (with Thymeleaf):
<form id="userForm" action="addObject" th:object="${objectToAdd}" method="POST">
        <input th:field="*{field1}" type="text" name="a" placeholder="a" required>
        <input th:field="*{field2}" type="text" name="b" placeholder="b" required>
        <input th:field="*{field3}" type="text" name="c" placeholder="c" required>
        <input th:field="*{field4}" type="text" name="d" placeholder="d" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

The object is of course being passed in @GetMapping controller:
@GetMapping("/form")
    public String getForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("objectToAdd", new SomeDto());
        return "form";
    }

and a @PostMapping destined to handle POST request from the form:
@PostMapping(value = "/form/addObject")
public ResponseEntity<?> addObject(@RequestBody SomeDto someDto) {
// some content
}

and when deployed, I am trying to submit form, and I get 415 HTTP error:
There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' is not supported.
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' is not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:213)

if I change @RequestBody to @RequestParam (because in the headers I see the form data are being "glued" to the address):
@PostMapping(value = "/form/addObject")
public ResponseEntity<?> addObject(@RequestParam(value = "someDto", required = false) ClientToAddDto clientToAddDto) {
// some code
}

I get an error indicating that someDto is null, and the error comes during someDto processing. (removing required = false, obviously results in error in submit itself).
even if I add "consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE", this does fix the error mentioned above. I'm not sure what is happening there, and why isn't the data from the form getting passed correctly to the backend... How do I submit form and process the data correctly?

"(because in the headers I see the form data are being "glued" to the address)" - if the parameters resulting from the form fields are getting appended to the resulting URL - then that would mean, your form submitted via GET, and not POST.

Use @ModelAttribute not @RequestBody.

@M. Deinum: right, @ModelAttribute worked. Also no annotation worked as well since it was in the Model. I don't understand this 100%, but well... as long as it works...

@RequestBody is for using with things like JSON/XML to (de)serialize to that format. @RequestParam is for simple request parameters and @ModelAttribute  for binding parameters to objects. All of this is also explained in the Spring Reference Guide (which I can suggest to read).
